# Clothing in Jordan

Tags: clothing, jordan

I'm a French man traveling to Jordan next month.
I wanted to know if there are specific cloths that I should not wear there.
I'm kind of a Metal dude, mainly wearing dark tee-shirts with "trashy" look. I'm also wearing many rings, wallet chains, I've got a long beard decorated with perls.

Is it accepted to dress that way in Jordan ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked my Jordanian friend. She told me that "You should be okay but do not wear a lot of chains and rings. No problem with dark clothes or metal look. If you are going to bars with your rings and chains then it's fine. However, downtown Amman and very traditional places it's better to be careful"

Comment: What if 'dark look' means symbols referring to daemons and occultism?

Comment: " it's better to be careful" this part is vague.. what do you mean by that? personally, seen all kinds of people in Amman, including downtown. No one really cared about others.

Comment: "No one really cared about others": well it's coming from a person who has spent her whole life in Amman. There must be some reason for her to say that.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you and your friend for your answer !